# Can't run Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sublimetext

Recently I am facing a problem and can't open my Sublime Text. It worked for me since few days ago. But now it's not working. When I type

```bash
sudo sublime
```

then it shows the following error. And it's not openning.

```bash
(sublime:16435): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GSimpleAsyncResult'

(sublime:16435): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GAsyncResult'

(sublime:16435): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(sublime:16435): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(sublime:16435): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(sublime:16435): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(sublime:16435): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to run it as super user? if it's because of the permissions, change your permissions in a way so your user and web server can read/write/access the fies

Comment: I used it with this same command in previous. I think `sudo` is not causing the problem. Also I tried to run without `sudo`. It shows same problem. @Arsham

Comment: "g_once_init_leave assertion" problem is due to an old policykit version ( probably ). I'm not using ubuntu ( I'm on a rolling release ) but it might surprise you if you upgrade your ubuntu. ST developer assumes you have the latest softwares. Plus try to create another user, run it in the new environment and see if it works ( without sudo )

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation in an old Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

The solution in my case was found by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```